# How to index into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a beginner. I have this list:

```
players = [{'name': 'John', 'points': '27', 'Played': '6'},
{'name': 'Emil', 'points': '43', 'Played' : '13'},
{'name': 'Susan', 'points': '11', 'Played': '2'},
{'name': 'Peter', 'points': '4', 'Played': '3'}]
```

What I would like to do was to be able to say:

```
players["John"]["score"]=newScore
players["john"]["Played"] = players["john"]["Played"]+1
```

This list represents like a list of objects, where the name is the primary key and then there's parameters for each object.

But of course that doesn't work, I'm able to touch elements by, for example by doing:

```
print (players[0]["score"])
```

and this would then print John's score alright, but with this way I would need to go through all players[x] to first compare if the name is the same, and then I can access it, it just doesn't seem so Pythonic to me.

How would you go about this in a Pythonic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your current data with a class that could provide the specialized update methods you specified, without changing the entire structure of your original data to begin with:

```
class Row:
   def __init__(self, row):
      self.row = row
   def __setitem__(self, _t, _val):
      self.row[_t] = str(_val)
   def __getitem__(self, _stat):
      return int(self.row[_stat])
   def __repr__(self):
      return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, str(self.row))

class Players:
   def __init__(self, data={}):
      self.data = {i['name']:Row(i) for i in data}
   def __getitem__(self, name):
      return self.data[name]
   def __setitem__(self, _name, _data):
      self.data[_name] = Row(_data)
   def __repr__(self):
      return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, str(self.data))

players = [{'points': '27', 'name': 'John', 'Played': '6'}, {'points': '43', 'name': 'Emil', 'Played': '13'}, {'points': '11', 'name': 'Susan', 'Played': '2'}, {'points': '4', 'name': 'Peter', 'Played': '3'}]
d = Players(players)
d['John']['points'] = 30
d["John"]["Played"] = d["John"]["Played"]+1
print(d['John'])
d['Bob'] = {'points': '2', 'Played': '5'}
```

Output:

```
Row({'points': '30', 'name': 'John', 'Played': '7'})
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, my mistake.  Please see my recent edit. Now it merely iterates once, when an instance of `Player` is created.

Comment: This is really cool, wish i could put all of you as answered. With this above, what if i want to add a new player on the fly ? would i have to run through the whole list or can it be made so i only have to run it on the one i add ?

Comment: @MTdrip Please see my recent edit. I added a `__setitem__` method in `Player` to enable creation of new players.

Comment: @MTdrip What Ajax said. But unfortunately it won't update the original `players` list, so when a new player is added to `d` it gets out of sync with `players`. Of course, there are ways around that, but things are starting to get complicated...

Comment: Yes just tested it and can see that players isnt updated when adding new players to 'd' - but what if just skip using "players" and instead build it all up in 'd' ? am not pro enough yet to quite spot what kinda of difference there is between players and 'd' - im loading players from the fly so will try here to see if i can make it work buidling it all up with 'd' - aka initializing 'players' with nothing ( if its possible ).

Comment: @MTdrip The goal of this solution is to keep the original data intact for further use later, while the class stores all mutations that would normally be applied to `players`. Your assumption is correct in the case of this solution: build the player results by using `d`.

Comment: i cant init it with nothing, but i can init 'd' with 1 record, and then i can just add to d that seems to work fine - what exactly is its doing, its adding functions to the structure we can call, but what kind of structure is it using for the list/dict ?

Comment: @MTdrip The underlying structure is still a dictionary stored as an attribute of the class; however, the class itself provides slightly different functionality by allowing you to apply the inverted methods of data lookup originally mentioned by utilizing builtin `__getitem__`/`__setitem__` methods.

Comment: cool i think im starting to understand it. I just did a little modification to the   setitem, if im trying to access a name that isnt already added it would come with and error so made this in _getitem__ :                                                if name in self.data :
            return self.data[name]
        else:
            return ""

Comment: @MTdrip Ah, good idea. You could also use `dict.get`: `return self.data.get(name, '')`.

Comment: yes that works too and is prettier - the '' means that in case it cant find it it will put '' as return ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170431/discussion-between-mt-drip-and-ajax1234).

Answer (score 7):

Change your data structure, if `Name` is a key then simply:

```
players_dict = {d['Name']: d for d in players}
```

would allow you to do:

```
players_dict["John"]["score"] = new_score
```

Comment: my god :) if you knew the amount of hours and ugly code i tried to get around this - this programming language is so beautiful. Do have an additional question for dictionaries and lists but better post it as a new question

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access those dicts by player name, it is better that you adapt the format of your data to this need.

E.g.:

```
playersDict = {o['name']: o for o in players}
```

Now you can youse `playersDict` as in your example:

```
>>> playersDict['John']['Played']
'6'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a list of dictionaries is inefficient and not a recommended solution to hold structured data of this kind.

You can use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) from the standard library, but I prefer 3rd party library `pandas`, which accepts a list of dictionaries directly:

```
import pandas as pd

players = [{'name': 'John', 'points': '27', 'Played': '6'},
           {'name': 'Emil', 'points': '43', 'Played' : '13'},
           {'name': 'Susan', 'points': '11', 'Played': '2'},
           {'name': 'Peter', 'points': '4', 'Played': '3'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(players)

print(df)

  Played   name points
0      6   John     27
1     13   Emil     43
2      2  Susan     11
3      3  Peter      4
```

You can then perform manipulations using the `pandas` API:

```
# Add a new column and specify value for a given name
df['Score'] = 0
df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'Score'] = 1

# Add 1 to John played
df.loc[df['name'] == 'John', 'Played'] += 1
```

Comment: why is the dictionary inefficient ? what i probably end out with in the end in this learning project, is that i would need a structure that would be a dictionary structure like i described here, but on the player, i would then attached an additonal list or dictionary, which would contain all games played by the player ( the games that adds up to the score) which could be many - would something like this be where i should look into the panda ?

Comment: It's ok to suggest Pandas when it's appropriate for a question that isn't tagged Pandas, but please bear in mind that not everyone want to use or install Pandas.

Comment: @MTdrip, A list of dictionaries is inefficient because it requires many levels of passing; first pass each list, then pass each dictionary; then check if key-value pair already exists, etc. If you aren't permitted to use `pandas`, please do look at the other solutions here. What I would say is there are *much better* data structures to use for learning purposes than a list of dictionaries; look up named tuples, for example.

Comment: @jpp thanks i will try to get around as much as possible as its learning phase and i dont rule out panda if it makes things easier for me and in the end faster, but probably will try to stick with as much standard as possible to start with as its still a new world to me but am absolutely hooked on this language

Comment: @PM2Ring, While I respect other opinions, I'm more than happy to take the downvotes. In my experience, this is a useful and valid solution when the question does not explicitly state a requirement for a pure Python solution.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't downvote an answer merely because it uses Pandas, or some other 3rd party library, that the OP didn't tag. Unless, of course, the solution were worse than a plain Python solution. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make new structure data for that.
e.g.

```
>>> new_data_struct_players = {}

>>> for player in players:
...    new_data_struct_players[player['name']] = {
...        'points': int(player['points']),  # make it number (int)
...        'Played': int(player['points'])   # make it number too
...    }

>>> print(new_data_struct_players['John'])
{'points': '27', 'Played': 27}

print(new_data_struct_players['John']['points'])
27
```

Comment: think i follow the idea here and its nice that it can act as integer - but i would like to update on the fly, im reading in lines from a text file, and when i meet "John-Lines" in the file i would like to update his stats, and if "John" isnt already in the list i want to add him. Am not sure but the above seems to be that i have to run through the datastructure every time in that case ? or would i be able to only run it if i add a previously unknown player to the dict ?